# Don't understand certain commands in this bash script

Tags: bash, unix

I've been tasked to modify this bash script and there are some syntax in this script that I don't quite understand.

I understand the majority after researching and studying some bash. I feel bad about posting the entire script here but I didn't want to hide any information from you that would make it harder to answer my questions.

Basically I have gap in understanding the following bash commands you'll find in the script below.

1. `if [[ ${#} -eq 3 ]]; then` - What is the `$#` here? What are `[[]]`?
2. `eval HOSTNAME_PORT=\$$ENV
    eval config_mapping_values=\$$MAPPING` - there are 2 $ here? What's up with the slash
3. `IFS=',' read -a mapping_value_array <<< "$mapping_values_param"`
4. `"${!mapping_value_array[@]}"` - What is @ sign here in the beginning of loop?
5. `type_name=$(echo $map_value_item | cut -d":" -f1)`- Why $ sign is used outside and inside of parenthesis?

The full script:

```
#!/bin/sh

insert_mapping()
{
  mapping_name_param=$1
  mapping_values_param=$2
  echo "Calling insert mapping: name: $mapping_name_param values: $mapping_values_param "

  IFS=',' read -a mapping_value_array <<< "$mapping_values_param"

  for index in "${!mapping_value_array[@]}"
  do
    map_value_item=${mapping_value_array[index]}

    if [[ $index -eq 0 ]];then
            echo "Calling Curl Command: curl -XPUT "$HOSTNAME_PORT/$mapping_name_param" -d @$map_value_item"
        curl -XPUT "$HOSTNAME_PORT/$mapping_name_param" -d @$map_value_item
    else
        type_name=$(echo $map_value_item | cut -d":" -f1)
        type_file=$(echo $map_value_item | cut -d":" -f2)
            echo "Calling Curl Command: curl -XPUT "$HOSTNAME_PORT/$mapping_name_param/$type_name/_mapping" -d @$type_file"
        curl -XPUT "$HOSTNAME_PORT/$mapping_name_param/$type_name/_mapping" -d @$type_file
    fi
  done
}

delete_mapping()
{
  mapping_name_param=$1
  echo "Calling Curl Command: curl -XDELETE "$HOSTNAME_PORT/$mapping_name_param""
  curl -XDELETE "$HOSTNAME_PORT/$mapping_name_param"
}

#
# MAIN METHOD
#
source ./configure_es_mapping_util.cfg

if [[ ${#} -eq 3 ]]; then
     export ENV=$1
     export ACTION=$2
     export MAPPING=$3
     echo "ENV: $ENV ACTION $ACTION MAPPING $MAPPING"

     eval HOSTNAME_PORT=\$$ENV
     eval config_mapping_values=\$$MAPPING

     if [[ "$ACTION" == "insert" || "$ACTION" == "INSERT" ]]; then
       if [[ "$MAPPING" == "all" ]]; then
          IFS=',' read -a all_mappings_array <<< "$all_mappings"
          for i in "${all_mappings_array[@]}"
          do
              eval config_mapping_values=\$$i
              insert_mapping $i $config_mapping_values
          done
       else
         insert_mapping $MAPPING $config_mapping_values
       fi
     elif [[ "$ACTION" == "delete" || "$ACTION" == "DELETE" ]]; then
        echo "Calling delete: $ACTION"
       if [[ "$MAPPING" == "all" ]]; then
          IFS=',' read -a all_mappings_array <<< "$all_mappings"
          for i in "${all_mappings_array[@]}"
          do
              delete_mapping $i
          done
       else
         delete_mapping $MAPPING
       fi
    else
        echo "unknown action"
    fi
else
    echo "Invalid Arguments: Provide Env(ITE, QA, UAT, PROD) Action(INSERT, DELETE) Mapping(icrd_alerts)"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Not a `sh` question -- several of these (#3, #4) are specifically bash constructs.

Comment: ...actually, #1 too, since it uses `[[ ]]`.

Comment: I don't know the difference between bash or sh.

Comment: Larger than that, though -- putting five questions in one "question" is bad form (close reason: "too broad"), and there's no attempt here to show your work for any of them ("I read documentation X, and it said Y, but that doesn't make sense to me because Z" would be the right way to do that for this kind of question).

Comment: But that would make the question more unbearable for you to read. I understand loops and if elif etc. And the $1 arguments etc. I had to learn this stuff

Comment: Take `if [[ ${#} -eq 3 ]]; then`, for instance. What, **specifically**, don't you understand? Is it `${#}`? Is it `[[ ]]`? Is it `-eq`?

Comment: Sorry, I understand `-eq` is comparing to 3. But what in the world is `${#}` and `[[]]`

Comment: `${#}` is a silly way to write `$#`. `[[ ]]` is a more flexible version of `[ ]` (special syntax, as opposed to a builtin command using normal parsing rules).

Comment: Let me modify the question a bit so its not as broad

Comment: I don't know what `$#` or `[]` is

Comment: `[ ]` is the command otherwise known as `test`. `man test` will tell you about it.

Comment: For `$#`, see the `Special Parameters` section in `man bash`.

Comment: I've modified my question for more specific commands.

Comment: And where is `"$all_mappings"` variable that's being appended using <<< coming from?

Comment: It's specific commands, but it's still a collection of questions asked as one. I'm not willing to endorse/condone that behavior (as it makes the "mark as duplicate" functionality useless -- since nobody else will have the exact 5 questions in one, even though all 5 might already be asked somewhere else), and it doesn't help StackOverflow's goal of building a knowledge base that's useful to other people (since having to dig through "questions" that are collections of things-this-one-guy-cared-about isn't helpful to others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [[ ${#} -eq 3 ]]; then
```

This statement tests whether the number of `position parameters` (e.g. the number of command line arguments) is `3`.

```
eval HOSTNAME_PORT=\$$ENV eval config_mapping_values=\$$MAPPING
```

the arguments to `eval` are read and concatenated together into a single command. The syntax `$$` is an `indirect reference`. Using eval here causes `HOSTNAME_PORT` to be set to the value of the variable `$(whatever $ENV is)`. Thus if `$ENV` contains "host1", `HOSTNAME_PORT=$host1`. The same applies for `config_mapping_values=\$$MAPPING`

```
IFS=',' read -a mapping_value_array <<< "$mapping_values_param"
```

`IFS` is the Bash `Internal Field Separator` (defautl is `$' \t\n'` (space tab newline)) that controls how `word-splitting` takes place. It causes the words in `"$mapping_values_param"` to be split on `,` and the result read into array `mapping_value_array`.

```
"${!mapping_value_array[@]}" in the loop beginning I see this.
```

The keys of an `associative array` are accessed using an exclamation point. At the beginning of a loop it simply returns a list of `key` values to iterate over. However, since the array `mapping_value_array` is a regular `indexed` array (See: `read -a mapping_value_array` above), the result is simply the indexes for each element in the array (e.g. `0 1 2 3...`).

```
type_name=$(echo $map_value_item | cut -d":" -f1)
```

The variable `type_name` is assigned the result of the `command substitution` (e.g. the result of `echo $map_value_item | cut -d":" -f1`).